# Product of n-th roots of unity theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The theorem states that

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}|1-w^k| = 1$$ where $w^k$s are n-th roots of unity.

Does anyone have any idea how to prove this theorem?

Comment: You can't prove this as it's wrong. The correct result is $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-w^k)=n$. (and it's without absolute value). To prove this, consider the polynomial $(1-X)^n-1$, and especially the coefficient of $X$.

Comment: Thank you! This confirm my guess and yes I have shown that indeed this is n !

Comment: @KevinJiang If you had the guess that the "theorem" is wrong, why did you ask the question in its present form? It is always recommendable to explain your own thoughts, what you have done and what your specific problems are. Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 1):

Note, as mentioned in the comments above, the correct result states $n=|1-\omega||1-\omega^2|\cdots|1-\omega^{n-1}|$.

Let $f(z)=z^n-1$. The roots of $f$ are (apart from $z=1$) are $\omega^i$ for $i \in \{1,2, \cdots, n-1\}$ where $w=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$. Note for a polynomial of degree $3$ (call the polynomial $R$), if roots of $R$ are $r_{1}$, $r_{2}$ and $r_{3}$ then $R'(r_{3})=(x-r_{1})(x-r_{2})$.
Similarly, here: $f'(1)=(z-\omega)(z-\omega^2)\cdots(z-\omega^{n-1})$.

But we see $f'(z)=nz^{n-1}$ (hence $f'(1)=n$), and that's nearly the whole argument.